# Extracting Images from PDF Files in .NET 7 using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with a PDF that contains images, and I need to extract these images from the PDF file.

I've experimented with several libraries for extracting images from PDFs. However, I've encountered compatibility issues with many of these libraries when using .NET 7 or older versions. Additionally, some of these libraries seem to rely on methods that are either missing, not properly documented, or have incorrect parameters in my chosen environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract images from PDF files and save them as PNG using [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) library on .NET 5/6/7 like this:

```
public void ExtractImages(string fileName)
{
    PDFFixedDocument doc = new PDFFixedDocument(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++) 
    { 
        PDFContentExtractor ce = new PDFContentExtractor(doc.Pages[i]);

        PDFVisualImageCollection extractedImages = ce.ExtractImages(true);

        for (int j = 0; j < extractedImages.Count; j++)
        {
            using (FileStream imageStream = File.Create($"page_{i}_image_{j}.png"))
            {
                extractedImages[j].Save(imageStream, PDFVisualImageSaveFormat.Png);
                imageStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I work for the company that develops the [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) library.

Answer (score 0):

it's working after the previous answer, and I added a few changes to be reading from Base64 instead of the file as follows.

```
public void ExtractImagesFromBase64(string base64Pdf)
    {
        byte[] pdfData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Pdf);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(pdfData);
        PDFFixedDocument doc = new PDFFixedDocument(stream);
        int pageNumber = 1;
        var dic = new Dictionary<Pages, string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            PDFContentExtractor ce = new PDFContentExtractor(doc.Pages[i]);
            PDFVisualImageCollection extractedImages = ce.ExtractImages(true);

            for (int j = 0; j < extractedImages.Count; j++)
            {
                using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    extractedImages[j].Save(imageStream, PDFVisualImageSaveFormat.Png);
                    imageStream.Flush();
                    byte[] imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
                    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    dic.Add((Pages)pageNumber, base64Image);
                }

                pageNumber++;
            }
        }
    }
```